# completion handler does not get called as supposed Swift

Tags: swift, closures, completionhandler

I am trying to get the uid from a completion handler so that I can construct a path and retrieve some items from my Firebase DB, but `myuserLogged` evaluates to nill by the time   `dbRef` gets called.

My issues is that my completion handler is called after `dbRef` has already been called and not the other way around. 
I thought that my code will be executed in line, 1. FIRAuth.auth()?...., 2. dbRef = FIRDatabase....

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    FIRAuth.auth()?.addAuthStateDidChangeListener({ (auth:FIRAuth,     user:FIRUser?) in
        if let userSignedIn = user {

            self.myuserLogged = userSignedIn.uid
            print("Welcome buddy \(self.myuserLogged)")

        }
    })
 print("brother \(self.myuserLogged)")

    dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users/\(myuserLogged)")
    startObservingDB()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completion handler is handled asynchronously, since the operation may take some time. If you need to have `dbRef` afterwards, you need to put this into the completion handler.

Comment: So basically it works in this way: while addAuthStateDidChangeListener is grabbing the info from the database and populates auth  & user variable, code execution continues to dbRef and  once addAuthStateDidChangeListener has finished its task, it will continue executing the code after   `in` . I think I got it.